# CSS not centering as expected

Tags: css

I'm trying to get this text to center in this div.  I'm using react so the class name is "className"

```css
.cartCost {
  background-color: #fffbe3;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 8px 0 5px 0;
}

.cartType {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cartCost">
  <div class="cartType">$0.00</div>
</div>
```

The result is this:
[image]

The text appears to the left not centered.

Comment: you need to also center the content inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align: center` on your element. Otherwise the text is always left aligned by default.

```css
.cartCost {
  background-color: #fffbe3;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 8px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.cartType {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cartCost">
  <div class="cartType">$0.00</div>
</div>
```